# Handling untracked attachments between backend and S3

Tags: amazon-s3, architecture

I wanted to ask if you have any proven ways to deal with removing non-tracked attachments from S3?

[Architecture diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whvr2.png)

I am using the S3 in project to hold files in a way that the Frontend fetching a pre-signed URL from Backend (1). Then Frontend adds an attachment to S3 (2), and then adds a URL to some resource (3).

The challenge is that there may be a difference between attachments on the server and URLs in the resource - eg Frontend getting the URL from Backend, sends file to S3, and does not add it to the Backend resource.

Does any of you have a way to deal with such a problem?

Fetching all the resources from database once in a day and comparing their attachments with those on the server sounds unsatisfactory. :/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Distributed consistency is hard sometimes...  Orphaned records in non-transactional systems are hard and expensive to track down.

You have to decide what your tolerance for data-consistency-drift is.  If you need it to be absolute, then you need to put in place things like rollbacks when transactions fail (e.g. when the writ to the backend fails, rollback the write to S3 when the backend write fails).  Alternatively you can tag files in S3 with a tag that says something like "backend:pending" when creating the files and update it to "backend:done" so that you can easily identify s3 objects that need cleanup.

A more scalable option would be to use something like SQS to manage your workflow, ensuring that both changes are handled, and creating hospital queues for when things go sideways.